# Change HTML attribute after using window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I want to open a new window on click of a button. Once the new window is open I want to change the zoom level to 80%.

After I open the window I take a reference object of the window and try to set the zoom level.

This is a sample code:

```js
    function openGoogle(){
      var obj = window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
      obj.document.body.style.zoom = 0.8;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>    
      <head>
        <script data-require="jquery@3.2.1" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <button onclick="openGoogle()">Open</button>
      </body>    
    </html>
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed by browsers to prevent XSS (cross site scripting).

You can start understanding XSS more here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)

What you can do, on the other hand, is pass `Window Features` into `window.open()` to specify height and width as well as some other flags. (**NOTE:** *I do not have experience with this feature, I'm not fully aware of what it is and isn't capable of*)

Window Features Documentation: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features

Comment: Height and width isn't an option. We have to fit a page within a window. So need to zoom.

Comment: You won't be able to do that. You do not have access to modify another sites content on a clients device with JS (The basis of what XSS is). This is to prevent malicious behavior, from unwanted data entry to effecting a viewers perception of a site. Kind of like you wouldn't want me to be able to send someone to your site and change your content to say something like "You've just been hacked"

Comment: That sounds right. Was checking if there would be any hack to do that. Looks like we can't then.

Comment: Is the zoom property of the html or of a browser.